# Python implementing my own linspace routine for plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am very new to python and am having trouble making a plot of a gaussian function using my linspace routine. (I don't want to use numpy).

```
"""plot a normalized gaussian function
"""
from matplotlib import pyplot as mp
import math 
def linspace(a,b,n):
    if n==1:
        yield b
        return
    d=(b-a)/(n-1)
    for i in range(n):
        yield a+d*i


def gaussian(x,xo, sig):
    return ((2*math.pi*sig**(2.))**(-1/2.))*(math.exp(((x-xo)**(2.))/(2*sig**(2.))))

for xo, sig in [(-1,0.5), (-1,1), (-1,2)]:
    mp.plot(gaussian(linspace(-3,3,1000),xo,sig))

mp.show()
```

The error is that i can't use this linspace in this way in the gaussian, but I'm not sure how I can fix this. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use NumPy? It's the natural way to solve this, and you're already using other third-party libraries from the scientific stack (matplotlib).  Indeed, NumPy is a dependency of matplotlib, so if you've got matplotlib installed, you should also already have NumPy.

Answer (score 1):

`plot()` does not accept generators. Furthermore, you cannot do mathematical operations on generators. So you need to call `gaussian()` for each element in `linspace()`.You could try:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as mp
import math


def linspace(a, b, n):
    if n == 1:
        yield b
        return
    d = (b-a)/(n-1)
    for i in range(n):
        yield a+d*i


def gaussian(x, xo, sig):
    xp = ((x-xo)**(2.))/(2*sig**(2.))
    return ((2*math.pi*sig**(2.))**(-1/2.)) * math.exp(-xp)


for xo, sig in [(-1, 0.5), (-1, 1), (-1, 2)]:
    y = list(gaussian(x, xo, sig) for x in linspace(-5, 10, 100))
    mp.plot(y)

mp.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need you use floats when performing the division to calculate `d`.

For example:

```
(3- (-3))/(1000-1)=0
(3.-(-3.))/(1000.-1.)=0.006
```

So, in your function, you could :

```
def linspace(a,b,n):
    if n==1:
        yield b
        return
    d=float(b-a)/float(n-1)
    for i in range(n):
        yield a+d*i
```

Without casting to float, the first 10 values of your linspace are returned as:

```
[-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3]
```

But, if you use the function above:

```
[-3.0, -2.993993993993994, -2.987987987987988, -2.981981981981982, -2.975975975975976, -2.96996996996997, -2.963963963963964, -2.957957957957958, -2.951951951951952, -2.945945945945946]
```